# Using exec-maven-plugin to run external program with secured token from azure pipeline

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

There are a number of questions on exec-maven-plugin here but this is different. I'm trying to run an external program using exec-maven-plugin with exec goal in maven. One of the arguments to be passes is a secured token defined on azure pipeline.

The issue is that if I hardcode the token, meaning the actual token value without securing it and I run the mvn exec:exec command, it works. But when I pass the secured token from azure pipeline, it fails to communicate with the external program.

Is there a way to decrypt this secure token before passing it as an argument in the exec-maven-plugin or is there any other way to get this to work?

Relevant part of the pom is:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.0</version>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <phase>package</phase>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>exec</goal>
                      </goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
              <configuration>
                  <executable>java</executable>
                  <arguments>
                      <argument>-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$(env.MAVEN_TRUST_STORE)</argument>
                      <argument>-jar</argument>
                      <argument>                            ${settings.localRepository}/com/github/externalprogram/ddd/$(ddd.version)/ddd-$(ddd.version).jar
                      </argument>
                      <argument>--externalprogram.url=https://xxxx.yyyy.com/</argument>
                      <argument>--externalprogram.proxy.host=${someproxy}</argument>
                      <argument>--externalprogram.proxy.port=0000</argument>
                      <argument>--externalprogram.api.token=$**(secure-token)**</argument>
                      <argument>--detect.maven.path=$(env.M2_HOME)/bin/$(mvn)</argument>
                      <argument>--detect.maven.include.plugins=true</argument>
                      <argument>--detect.maven.build.command=-s $(env.MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML) -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$(env.MAVEN_TRUST_STORE)
                      </argument>
                      <argument>--detect.included.detector.types=maven,pip,npm</argument>
                      <argument>
                          --detect.externalprogram.signature.scanner.exclusion.name.patterns=*target*,*/target,*\target
                      </argument>
                      <argument>--detect.bdio2.enabled=false</argument>
                      <argument>--detect.project.version.phase=$(versionPhase)</argument>
                      <argument>--detect.code.location.name=${project.version}</argument>
                  </arguments>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

So if I replace the secure-token with the actual value, it works. But when I use the secured value it fails with error: Fails to communicate with external program. Not authorized...

Answer (score 0):

How are you defining the secure token?

**Note:** secret variables are not passed to environment variables by default

**Ref:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables